# docker phpmyadmin container exporting DBs as html instead of sql

Tags: docker, centos7, debian-stretch, phpmyadmin

My phpmyadmin container is exporting sql databases as html files when explicitly set to export as a sql file.

I've already updated the php.ini file to 
`max_input_vars = 10000` and `max_allowed_packet=500M`
 in my.cnf

Comment: What do you mean? Exactly how are you exporting?

Comment: Pressing the 'Export' button... Through the phpmyadmin interface... Selecting a DB -> Export -> Format: SQL -> Go